# Self joining two tables via third table

Tags: mysql, join

I have an interesting situation when a table records intricately relate with each others via column combination in another table.

I have `entity` table

```
entity_id | owner_id | title        | entity_type |  
    --------------------------------------------
       1  |     3    | some title 1 | supertype
       2  |     2    | some title 2 | supertype
       3  |     2    | some title 3 | supertype
       4  |     5    | title 1      | type_1
       5  |     5    | title 2      | type_2
       6  |     5    | title 3      | type_3
```

Then I have another table that stores various properties in key-value style

Table `entity_properties`:

```
property_id | entity_id | property_key | property_value
   112        | 1         | identifier   | type_1
   124        | 2         | identifier   | type_2
   146        | 3         | identifier   | type_3
   634        | 1         | is_cool      | 0
   135        | 2         | is_cool      | 1
   23         | 3         | is_cool      | 1
```

Now what I want is to select the entities with entity_type having values of `type_1`, `type_2`, `type_3`, and also have the column of `property_value` from `entity_properties` that would display `is_cool` parameter of an entity that has `property_key` = `identifier` with property_value that matches the entity type of my sought items from `entity` table.

desired results:

```
  entity_id | owner_id | title      | entity_type | property_value 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
         4  |     5    | title 1    | type_1      |  0  
         5  |     5    | title 2    | type_2      |  1
         6  |     5    | title 3    | type_3      |  1
```

I have been bashing my head against this one for a few days and this is the best approximation which is not working...

```
SELECT
    sought.*,
    entity_properties.property_value
FROM
    entity AS sought
INNER JOIN
    entity AS entity_type
JOIN
    entity_properties AS properties
ON
    properties.entity_id = entity_type.entity_id
WHERE
    sought.owner_id = 5 AND sought.entity_type IN(
        'type_1',
        'type_2',
        'type_3') 
AND properties.property_key = 'is_cool'
```

Comment: update your question and add  the expected result

Comment: @scaisEdge done

Comment: @RWS `entity_properties.entity_id` 4~6 `entity_id` = 1~3, can't match your expect result. what's your logic in your query.

Comment: @RWS  .. i have post  an aswer  hope is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the way your data is set up, your query will only work for entity IDs 1, 2, and 3, because there isn't a 4, 5, 6 in the entity_id column of the second entity_properties table. If you switched to join on property_id  you should get what you're looking for, although this may not be "right" depending on how your database is designed.

`SELECT
    sought.*,
    entity_properties.property_value
FROM
    entity AS sought
INNER JOIN
    entity AS entity_type
JOIN
    entity_properties AS properties
ON
    properties.property_id = entity_type.entity_id
WHERE
    sought.owner_id = 5 AND sought.entity_type IN(
        'type_1',
        'type_2',
        'type_3') 
AND properties.property_key = 'is_cool'`

Comment: ` properties.property_id = entity_type.entity_id` This will not work, as property_id has an independent numeration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use  two join on entity_properties

```
select e.entity_id, e.owner_id, e.title, e.entity_type, p2.property_value 
from entity  e 
inner join  entity_properties p1 on e.entity_type  = p1.property_value 
          and p1.property_key ='indentifier'
inner join  entity_properties p2 on p1.entity_id  = p2.entity_id 
          and p2.property_key ='is_cool'
```

Comment: you meant `inner join  entity_properties p2 on e.entity_id  = p1.entity_id ` on line 5. While this is a new approach, it returns 0 results still. I appreciate the try though.

Comment: Returns zero rows still. I appreciate the attempt immensely.

Comment: answer  updated .. the self join is between  p1 and p2  ..  for retrive the entity_id that match  ..

Comment: Now we have excessive amount of results. Please note there is no such column as `property_entity_id`. I have updated my question: `property_id` column in `entity_properties` table is now irrelevant, as  it should be.

Comment: .updated  answer  with . column entity_id ... but i don't undesrtand  "Now we have excessive amount of results" ... should return 3 rows